# Changing from tf::Transform to tf::StampedTransform

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could someone try to change any part of my code in order to use tf::StampedTransform. I've been trying to just replace it in place of tf::Transform directly, it doesn't work. I should have been missing something I think. This is needed because I cannot see the base_link movement with respect to the world. I think the tf is not correctly published with the below code.

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud; //Class variable

//    In a callback function
{
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 c_tmp;

static tf::TransformBroadcaster tfb;
tf::Transform xform;
xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(pose3D_LDD.pose.position.x, pose3D_LDD.pose.position.y, pose3D_LDD.pose.position.z));
xform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.x, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.y, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.z, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.w));
tfb.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(xform, ros::Time(pose3D_LDD.header.stamp), "world", "base_link"));
tfListener_.waitForTransform("world", "base_link", previous_scan_.header.stamp, ros::Duration(1.0));

try
{
    projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("laser", previous_scan_, c_tmp, tfListener_);

    if (!initialized_cloud_)
    {
        cloud = c_tmp;
        initialized_cloud_ = true;
    }
    else
    {
         pcl::concatenatePointCloud(cloud, c_tmp, cloud);

         ROS_INFO("From c_tmp: Got cloud with %u of width and %u of height", c_tmp.width, c_tmp.height);
         ROS_INFO("From cloud: Got cloud with %u of width and %u of height", cloud.width, cloud.height);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12864/changing-from-tf::transform-to-tf::stampedtransform/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do exactly the same thing, and it works for me. The only difference is that I put a "/" in front of all my frame_id's (so "world" becomes "/world"). That, and instead of `ros::Time(pose3D_LDD.header.stamp)`, I just use `pose3D_LDD.header.stamp` directly.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-03**:
As long as the distance between /world and /base_link is not large, I'd set both target and fixed frames to /world

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-02**:
What frame did you check/tick  each for Fixed Frame and Target Frame in your rviz? or in the above case supposedly?